# Can I travel to non eu country which rejected visa application, using valid multi entry schengen visa

Tags: visa-refusals, schengen-visas, multiple-entry

I had applied for a specific non European country recently and got rejected. Currently I have multi entry schengen visa. So can i visit to that specific country with using this visa.
It can trouble me during immigration ?

Comment: Which country are you attempting to enter using your Schengen visa? It matters.